# Varios Filtros C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

tengo datagridview que obtiene los datos de una BBDD sql, quiero filtrar los datos de dos formas, que me muestre por fecha pero que también me muestre si una de las columnas de la bbdd su valor es falso, independientemente de la fecha, es decir por ejemplo, que me muestre los registros del día 2-1-2023 y también un registro del dia 12-12-2022 que tiene valor falso en la columna 13 y otro del día 11-12-2022 que tiene valor falso en la columna 13.

para la fecha lo tengo asi:

```
        BindingSource bsc = new BindingSource();
        bsc.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        string filter = String.Format("fecha >= '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' AND fecha < '{1:yyyy- 
        MM-dd}'", dateTimePicker1.Value, dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1));
        bsc.Filter = filter;
```

Comment: ok.. encierra eso entre parentesis y agrega un or... no funciono eso???

Comment: si la fecha si funciona, lo que no se es como hacer que me muestre el otro filtro

Comment: Agrega tu otro filtro con un or ;)